# Wordpress theme not creating own menu on live server

Tags: wordpress, themes, blogs

I have a strange problem. I bought a theme called miniblog and it should have a "Theme options" menu item, where I basically set up everything.

At first, I added a site to my multisite network, switched the theme and couldn't find the menu. There were no plugins active on the site itself, but then I thought it was because of some network-wide plugins. So I installed a fresh WP on my localhost, tried it, and it worked.

I didn't want to have a separate WP install for this blog, but I guess I could live with it... so I installed a fresh WP on my server, uploaded the theme (no plugins at all) and... again there is no "Theme options" in the menu!

So I tried to copy the link to the set up page from my localhost, but I got the insufficient permissions error message.

What the heck is going on here? The theme I bought is practically useless this way. Any ideas?

Comment: stupid question: did you check your file permissions ?

Comment: I did, they seemed to be the same as on my other themes, but that's all Total Commander could tell me. I'm going to check with FileZilla now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I even tried to give all files 777 permissions, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: well, given the 'insufficient permission' error message, you'd think you could have something to do with file permission

Comment: if it did work on your localhost, but for some shady reason it´s not working live, AND you are getting that particular error, that seems to me some sort of server related/file permission issue. Maybe ownership has something to do with it (idk, i'm wild guessing here). Read this, maybe it'll help http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/

Comment: Please check whether the content of any files get messed up or not. I had a same issue over one of my site.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: could it be something in your .httaccess out of the ordinary ?

Comment: It very well could, but I can't imagine what would that be. Remember, I tried it with a fresh WP install on the server and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and see if any errors appear on your remote host. And post the errors here so we can help debug any issues that appear.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/Hs1S2RFg
There seems to be some code trying to build some menu options... maybe we're on to something here...

Comment: I just deleted the files from the server, uploaded them again (from my localhost installation) and... I can't believe it, but it suddenly works! Thanks for your time, all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to turn off menu points via php functions. You could either look for this by yourself, for example in the functions.php, or paste the code in here with PASETBIN or something similiar....

Probably the code could look like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');   
}
```

P.S.:link-manager.php is only an example.

Comment: Not sure I follow... I didn't do any amends to the functions.php and I don't think the theme creator would have disabled menu items in a very strange only-on-live-server way.